# Serve single application from multiple domain/subdomain in Nginx?

Tags: laravel, nginx, multi-tenant, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to pass/set custom header from Nginx block to server (not response header) to detect the tenant.

I have tried with Nginx proxy but failed: Here is my code:

```
server {
server_name   app.another.com www.app.another.com;

location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;       
       proxy_set_header        tenant-id 1001;
       proxy_pass       ...domain.com ;
       proxy_redirect   ...domain.com  ....app.another.com;
       }
 }
```

Error:
" 786 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream "

I also change worker_connections to 20000 but show

" ... accept4() failed (24: Too many open files) ..."
&
"... socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream ..."

after fixing this error the again arise previous error.

I also tried without proxy but can not pass custom header to request (not in response).

```
location / {
  add_header        tenant-id 10010;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

*** It's a Laravel based Application.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed.

-- must pass local host (with port) like: localhost:808 / 127.0.0.1:808 (if same ip)

-- Laravel generates URL with HTTP (not https) because we proxy_pass to http://localhost.

For fixing this issue add

```
 URL::forceScheme('https')
```

to AppServiceProvider inside boot method;